# Can the gitlab artifact created in step one be used in the docker straightway at step 2

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

My pipeline has couple of steps. The first step we had is to build the artifact (build-artifact shown below) for the .Net application.

```
  build-artifact:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster
      stage: build-artifact
      script:
        - dotnet restore
        - dotnet publish -c Release -o ./published
      artifacts:
        paths:
          - ./published/
```

I am able to access the published folder in the subsequent stages of the pipeline. However at one of the stage I have a docker step and tried to access the published folder like below, which I cant do.

```
 COPY ./published .
```

Can someone suggest how to get this gitlab artifact accessed in the docker file.

Comment: You can always use commands to list files in directory in before scripts, but that is correct logic. I would check the structure of root project folder before docker scripts.

Comment: Thanks Nemanja. Yeah I have the wrong docker folder context, I cant go back to the parent folder of the docker file. Once I move the docker file accessible I can access published.

Answer (score 0):

I have the wrong docker folder context, I cant go back to the parent folder of the docker file. Once I move the docker file accessible I can access published.